# how are pages initialized in IA-32 with 512MB physical memory?

Tags: x86, operating-system, paging, 32-bit

I'm currently, studying segmentation and paging of IA-32 system.

but there's one thing i don't understand.

On initialization (of Kernel page Directory,page Entry, pages), what address should pages be mapped up to?

boot information says its size is 512MB, so it detects 512MB of physical memory and it can allocate up to only 130818 pages (4KB pages).

As far as i know, In IA-32, the virtual address starts from 0x80000000 and goes up to 0xFFFFFFFF.

And i think, 0x00000000~0xFFFFFFFF should be all mapped by pages (please, correct me if I'm wrong)

but if i map pages on 512MB size of physical memory, page allocation is not possible anymore (no more than 130813)

is it possible to map all those pages ( 0x00000000 ~ 0xFFFFFFFF )?

summaries of my questions are,

1. what address should pages be mapped up to in IA-32 with 512MB size of physical memory?
2. is it possible to map all addresses(0~4GB)?

Comment: Where do you get the number 130818 from? Maximum number of pages with non-PAE paging on IA32 is 1048576 4KiB pages for a total of 4GiB. With PAE (Page address extensions) enabled it is 64GiB of physical address space that can be mapped (although virtual address space is still 4GiB)

Comment: As for what physical memory is actually present that can be mapped you have to query the BIOS (Legacy or UEFI BIOS) to give you a mapping of physical memory that is present. With legacy BIOS that is done with Int 0x15/AH=0xE820 https://wiki.osdev.org/Detecting_Memory_(x86)#BIOS_Function:_INT_0x15.2C_EAX_.3D_0xE820, With UEFI it is done via function `BootServices->GetMemoryMap`

Comment: I'm working on geekos project. actually I don't understand full side of how it is initialized but when it is booted, main.c calls VM initialization function and it gets bootinfo structure as a parameter, and it indicates the max pages i can allocate up to. that's where i get that number 130818. and sorry but i'm not allowed to touch other things like BIOS on this project.

Comment: I took a look at GeekOS briefly. It appears that it uses the memory map provided by GRUB (multiboot). It computes the total amount of physical memory from the memory map and then breaks that up into available pages. 130818 is the number of pages to map all physical memory from what I can tell. If you reduce the size of your VM (like QEMU) memory the number of pages should drop accordingly.

Comment: so i should map 130818 pages for kernel on initialization and drop the memory of VM down to 512MB?